# Run C Function in Separate Threads with Local Global Variables

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, global

I have some C source code that calls functions which modify global values. I would like to be able to run multiple, somewhat independent instances of the main code without sharing the global variables attached to the functions that are called. The main code is in a separate source file than the function definitions and the global variables, so the main function does not have direct access to the global variables. Is there a way to have multiple instances of the main code which calls functions with their own copies of global variables?

I've looked at threads, but the global variables will be shared between the threads. I've also looked at running two separate processes, and just use interprocess communication to communicate between the multiple instances, but that seems like too much work for what I want to do.

The optimal solution would be to have separate threads that each had their own copy of global variables that the functions use.

I was just wondering if anyone else had solved a similar problem through a simpler route.

EDIT: The functions with globals that I am calling are not my code, so I can't exactly modify the globals or the functions that call them.

Example code to help clarify the problem:

```
// In func.c

int g_A = 0;
void func()
{
    g_A++;
}


// In main.cpp

void Thread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        func();
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Could be threads, just looking for something that will allow 
    // me to run the "Thread" function in multiple parallel instances 
    // without sharing the global variables attached to the function 
    // that it calls
    std::thread foo1(func);
    std::thread foo2(func);
    foo1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Child processes sounds like what you'll need -- either that, or refactor your code so that (the variables that need to be different for each thread) are no longer global.

Comment: can you provide some example code?

Comment: Refactoring wasn't really an option since the functions aren't my code, but I'll look into child processes.

Comment: You need to make up your mind whether your question is about C++ or C. C++11 has the `thread_local` storage class.

Comment: Well, the functions with globals that I am calling are in C and must be kept in C, but I can use C++ in the main code or behind the scenes.

Comment: It sounds like you need thread-local storage.  C11 and C++11 both have it.  In C11, it is designated by `_Thread_local` without needing any header, or `thread_local` if you include `<threads.h>` (i.e. `<threads.h>` contains `#define thread_local _Thread_local`, at least in effect).  Always supposing your C11 implementation includes thread support (neither GCC 6.1.0 nor clang (Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)) have such support on Mac OS X 10.11.5).

Comment: You talked about the variables that you _don't_ want to share amongst all threads.  Is there anything that you _do_ want to share (either memory or some common file, socket or other OS resource)?  If there isn't, different processes should work easily for you.  And even if you really want to share data, you could use shared memory, semaphores, memory-mapped files or some other IPC mechanism.

Comment: I need to be able to send and receive data to and from each thread, but the process by which I do that does not have to be based in C. I'm thinking that separate processes with some sort of IPC are probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, "globals" are global to the entire *process*.

It sounds like you're looking for something like [Thread Local Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  These variables are associated with an individual "thread".

You didn't mention your platform or your threading API, but here are a couple of links that might help:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- http://dulanja.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-use-thread-local-storage-tls-in.html